How do I get the IDs from tables in order for the _deleteData to work?
The database that I'm using is Supabase and the IDs of "Guest" and "passenger_manifest" tables are both identities. In my QRPage.dart code below, I'm trying to use _deleteData to delete the information that was inputted from GuestRegistration.dart and it doesn't delete it when I press the back button. It shows the ID in the debug console, but it doesn't delete the row.
QRPage.dart code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/GuestRegistration.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(
        firstNameController: TextEditingController(),
        surnameController: TextEditingController(),
        professionController: TextEditingController(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? id;
  final int? guest_id;
  final String? origin;
  final String? destination;
  final TextEditingController firstNameController;
  final TextEditingController surnameController;
  final TextEditingController professionController;

  const HomePage({
    super.key,
    this.id,
    this.guest_id,
    this.origin,
    this.destination,
    required this.firstNameController,
    required this.surnameController,
    required this.professionController,
  });

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}


class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final SupabaseClient _supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('E-Ticket'),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7ADFC1),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            _showExitConfirmationDialog();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Color(0xFF7ADFC1), Color(0xFF21A5D1)],
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 350,
                height: 550,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    QrImageView(
                      data: widget.destination ?? '',
                      version: QrVersions.auto,
                      size: 300.0,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.firstNameController.text} ${widget.surnameController.text}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      widget.professionController.text,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.origin ?? ''} - ${widget.destination ?? ''}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Total Fee:',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '₱0.00',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showConfirmationDialog(context);
                },
                child: const Text('Complete Transaction'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showExitConfirmationDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text('Do you want to go back? This will delete the input data.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _deleteData(); 
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

Future<void> _deleteData() async {
  try {
    if (widget.id == null) {
      print('Error: No ID to delete.');
      return;
    }

    
    await _supabase.from('passenger_manifest').delete().eq('id', widget.id!);

    
    await _supabase.from('Guest').delete().eq('id', widget.guest_id!);

    print('Data deleted successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error deleting data: $error');
  }
}


  void showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text('Do you want to complete the transaction?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


and this is my GuestRegistration.dart code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/CustomTextBoxes.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/DropBoxes.dart';
import 'package:namer_app/Passenger_Widgets/UserEmailRegistration.dart';
import 'package:philippines_rpcmb/philippines_rpcmb.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'QRPage.dart';

void main() async {
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://bdhoonwrqbdvkhatpxdv.supabase.co',
    anonKey:
        'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6ImJkaG9vbndycWJkdmtoYXRweGR2Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MjMwMDY4NTIsImV4cCI6MjAzODU4Mjg1Mn0.TOHOu-NNXVwNLOWauZFvzDTPYmhKZJOXD6WEmVPP1cQ',
  );

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Guest Registration',
    home: PrfGuestRegistration(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class PrfGuestRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
  const PrfGuestRegistration({super.key});

  @override
  State<PrfGuestRegistration> createState() => _PrfGuestRegistrationState();
}

class _PrfGuestRegistrationState extends State<PrfGuestRegistration> {
  Region? region;
  Province? province;
  Municipality? municipality;
  String? barangay;
  String? selectedGender;
  String? selectedOrigin;
  String? selectedDestination;
  int? _id;
  int? _guest_id;
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final middleInitialController = TextEditingController();
  final surnameController = TextEditingController();
  final contactController = TextEditingController();
  final professionController = TextEditingController();
  final ageController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> _errors = [];

  void _validatePassword(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _errors.clear();

      
      if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'))) {
        _errors.add("Must contain lowercase.");
      }
      if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))) {
        _errors.add("Must contain uppercase.");
      }
      if (value.length < 8) {
        _errors.add("At least 8 characters.");
      }
      if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
        _errors.add("At least one number.");
      }
      if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]'))) {
        _errors.add("At least one special character.");
      }
    });
  }

  String? _validateRequired(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'This field is required';
    }
    return null;
  }

void _submitForm() async {
  final form = _formKey.currentState;
  if (form!.validate()) {
    if (selectedOrigin == selectedDestination) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text("Origin and destination cannot be the same. Please choose a different destination."),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }

    final data = {
      'first_name': firstNameController.text,
      'middle_name': middleInitialController.text,
      'last_name': surnameController.text,
      'address': municipality?.name,
      'contact_number': contactController.text,
      'profession': professionController.text,
      'age': ageController.text,
      'gender': selectedGender,
      'origin': selectedOrigin,
      'destination': selectedDestination,
    };

    try {
      final response = await Supabase.instance.client.from('passenger_manifest').insert([data]).select('id').single();
      
          if (response.containsKey('error')) {
      print('Error inserting data: ${response['error']}');
    } else {
      final id = response['id']; 
      print('Registration successful, ID: $id');
    }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error inserting data: $e');
    }
  }

  if (form!.validate()) {
    
    final data = {
      'first_name': firstNameController.text,
      'middle_initial': middleInitialController.text,
      'last_name': surnameController.text,
      'contact_num': contactController.text,
      'profession': professionController.text,
      'age': ageController.text,
      'gender': selectedGender,
      'region': region!.regionName,
      'province': province?.name,
      'municipality': municipality?.name,
      'barangay': barangay,
      'origin': selectedOrigin,
      'destination': selectedDestination,
    };

    try {
      final response = await Supabase.instance.client.from('Guest').insert([data]).select('guest_id').single();
      
          if (response.containsKey('error')) {
      print('Error inserting data: ${response['error']}');
    } else {
      final guest_id = response['guest_id']; 
      print('Registration successful, ID: $guest_id');
    }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error inserting data: $e');
    }
  }
}


  void handleGenderSelected(String? gender) {
    setState(() {
      selectedGender = gender;
    });
  }

  void handleOriginSelected(String? origin) {
    setState(() {
      selectedOrigin = origin;
    });
  }

  void handleDestinationSelected(String? destination) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDestination = destination;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4FCAD2),
          title: Center(
            child: const Text(
              "Guest Registration",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF33385F),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'EBGaramond',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/prf_logo.png',
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  FirstMiddleTextBox(
                    firstNameController: firstNameController,
                    middleController: middleInitialController,
                    validator: _validateRequired,
                  ),
                  SurnameTextBox(
                    textController: surnameController,
                    validator: _validateRequired,
                  ),
                  LocationDropdowns(
                    isEnabled: true,
                    onRegionChanged: (selectedRegion) {
                      setState(() {
                        region = selectedRegion;
                        province = null;
                        municipality = null;
                        barangay = null;
                      });
                    },
                    onProvinceChanged: (selectedProvince) {
                      setState(() {
                        province = selectedProvince;
                        municipality = null;
                        barangay = null;
                      });
                    },
                    onMunicipalityChanged: (selectedMunicipality) {
                      setState(() {
                        municipality = selectedMunicipality;
                        barangay = null;
                      });
                    },
                    onBarangayChanged: (selectedBarangay) {
                      setState(() {
                        barangay = selectedBarangay;
                      });
                    },
                    region: region,
                    province: province,
                    municipality: municipality,
                    barangay: barangay,
                  ),
                  ContactNumTextBox(
                    textController: contactController,
                    validator: _validateRequired,
                  ),
                  ProfessionAgeTextBox(
                    professionController: professionController,
                    professionValidator: _validateRequired,
                    ageController: ageController,
                    ageValidator: _validateRequired,
                  ),
                  OriginAgeBox(
                    onGenderChanged: handleGenderSelected,
                    onOriginChanged: handleOriginSelected,
                  ),
                  DesitinationDropBox(
                    onDestinationChanged: handleDestinationSelected,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  SubmitButton(onPressed: _submitForm, 
                  firstNameController: firstNameController,
                  surnameController: surnameController,
                  professionController: professionController,
                  origin: selectedOrigin,
                  destination: selectedDestination,
                  id: _id,
                  guest_id: _guest_id,),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ProfessionAgeTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController professionController;
  final TextEditingController ageController;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? professionValidator;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? ageValidator;
  const ProfessionAgeTextBox(
      {super.key,
      required this.professionController,
      required this.ageController,
      required this.professionValidator,
      required this.ageValidator});

  @override
  State<ProfessionAgeTextBox> createState() => _ProfessionAgeTextBoxState();
}

class _ProfessionAgeTextBoxState extends State<ProfessionAgeTextBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 0, 8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          URCustomTexboxes(
            validator: widget.professionValidator,
            myKeyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textController: widget.professionController,
            hintText: 'Enter profession',
            labelText: 'Profession',
            containerWidth: 190,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          URCustomTexboxes(
            textController: widget.ageController,
            validator: widget.ageValidator,
            isRequired: true,
            restrictToDigits: true,
            myKeyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            hintText: 'Enter age',
            labelText: 'Age',
            containerWidth: 80,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SurnameTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController textController;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  const SurnameTextBox(
      {super.key, required this.textController, required this.validator});

  @override
  State<SurnameTextBox> createState() => _SurnameTextBoxState();
}

class _SurnameTextBoxState extends State<SurnameTextBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 8),
      child: URCustomTexboxes(
        validator: widget.validator,
        isRequired: true,
        restrictToStrings: true,
        myKeyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textController: widget.textController,
        hintText: 'Enter surname',
        labelText: 'Surname',
        containerWidth: 280,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OriginAgeBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String?) onOriginChanged;
  final Function(String?) onGenderChanged;

  const OriginAgeBox({
    super.key,
    required this.onOriginChanged,
    required this.onGenderChanged,
  });

  @override
  State<OriginAgeBox> createState() => _OriginAgeBoxState();
}

class _OriginAgeBoxState extends State<OriginAgeBox> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get genderItems {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Male"), value: "Male"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Female"), value: "Female"),
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get ferryStations {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Pinagbuhatan"), value: "Pinagbuhatan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Kalawaan"), value: "Kalawaan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("San Joaquin"), value: "San Joaquin"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Guadalupe"), value: "Guadalupe"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Hulo"), value: "Hulo"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Valenzuela"), value: "Valenzuela"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Lambingan"), value: "Lambingan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Sta.Ana"), value: "Sta.Ana"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("PUP"), value: "PUP"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Quinta"), value: "Quinta"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Lawton"), value: "Lawton"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Escolta"), value: "Escolta"),
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }

  String selectedGender = "";
  String selectedOrigin = "";
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 0, 8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 9),
            child: Container(
                height: 68,
                width: 176,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    isDense: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                          color: Color(0xFF33385F),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 2,
                          color: Color(0xFF33385F),
                        ),
                      ),
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
                    ),
                    hint: Text("Select origin"),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 9,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOrigin = newValue!;
                      });
                      widget.onOriginChanged(newValue);
                    },
                    items: ferryStations)),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 9),
            child: Container(
                height: 68,
                width: 95,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  isDense: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 2,
                        color: Color(0xFF33385F),
                      ),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 2,
                        color: Color(0xFF33385F),
                      ),
                    ),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 6),
                  ),
                  hint: Text("Select gender"),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 9,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedGender = newValue!;
                    });
                    widget.onGenderChanged(newValue);
                  },
                  items: genderItems,
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DesitinationDropBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String?) onDestinationChanged;

  const DesitinationDropBox({super.key, required this.onDestinationChanged});

  @override
  State<DesitinationDropBox> createState() => _DesitinationDropBoxState();
}

class _DesitinationDropBoxState extends State<DesitinationDropBox> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get ferryStations {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Pinagbuhatan"), value: "Pinagbuhatan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Kalawaan"), value: "Kalawaan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("San Joaquin"), value: "San Joaquin"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Guadalupe"), value: "Guadalupe"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Hulo"), value: "Hulo"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Valenzuela"), value: "Valenzuela"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Lambingan"), value: "Lambingan"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Sta.Ana"), value: "Sta.Ana"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("PUP"), value: "PUP"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Quinta"), value: "Quinta"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Lawton"), value: "Lawton"),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Escolta"), value: "Escolta"),
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }

  String selectedDestination = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 9),
      child: Container(
        height: 68,
        width: 282,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          isDense: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 2,
                color: Color(0xFF33385F),
              ),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 2,
                color: Color(0xFF33385F),
              ),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 5),
          ),
          hint: Text("Select destination"),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 9,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDestination = newValue!;
            });
            widget.onDestinationChanged(newValue);
          },
          items: ferryStations,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubmitButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String? origin;
  final String? destination;
  final TextEditingController firstNameController;
  final TextEditingController surnameController;
  final TextEditingController professionController;
  final int? id;
  final int? guest_id;

  const SubmitButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.origin,
    this.destination,
    required this.firstNameController,
    required this.surnameController,
    required this.professionController,
    this.id,
    this.guest_id,

  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 280,
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text("Confirm Your Selection"),
                content: Text(
                    "Are you sure you want to proceed with the following selections?\n\nOrigin: $origin\nDestination: $destination"),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
                    },
                    child: const Text("Cancel"),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      if (origin != destination) {
                        onPressed();
                        
                        if (origin != null && destination != null) {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => HomePage(
                                id: id,
                                guest_id: guest_id,
                                origin: origin,
                                destination: destination,
                                firstNameController: firstNameController,
                                surnameController: surnameController,
                                professionController: professionController,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Origin and destination cannot be the same. Please choose a different destination."),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Proceed"),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Text("SUBMIT"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF4FCAD2),
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF33385F),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried storing the IDs on the registration and passing the IDs from GuestRegistration.dart to QRPage.dart.
